# Regex plus variable in Nginx `proxy_redirect`

Tags: nginx, config, nginx-config

Nginx `proxy_redirect` allows the use of variables such as `$my_var` and regular expressions, prefixed with `~`.

But it seems impossible to use them both in combination. Is this possible, and what is the correct syntax for escaping meta-characters?

For example, I've tried:

```
proxy_redirect ~*https?://\\$proxy_host/(.*)$ /app1/$1
proxy_redirect ~*https?://\$proxy_host/(.*)$ /app1/$1
proxy_redirect ~*https?://$proxy_host/(.*)$ /app1/$1
```

Obviously the last example is incorrect, as the `$` before `proxy_host` is interpreted as a regex meta character. But the two other examples don't work either. (They aren't recognized and so don't rewrite the `Location` header.

When I replace with just

```
proxy_redirect ~*https?://[^/]+/(.*)$ /app1/$1
```

the redirect works just fine.

The issue is that this will redirect even for external redirects, so is too inclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables and regular expressions are mutually exclusive.

To match both `http` and `https` you could just use two consecutive statements, for example:

```
proxy_redirect http://$proxy_host/ /app1/;
proxy_redirect https://$proxy_host/ /app1/;
```

Anything following the matched string is automatically appended to the replacement string, so a regular expression is not necessary needed.